# ReactD3 is not defined in react using d3 charts

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, chart.js, bar-chart, react-d3

I am following [this](https://techhandle.net/libraries-code/react-d3-components.html) site for bar chart in d3 for React.

```
getting error " ReactD3 is undefined" 
var BarChart = ReactD3.BarChart;
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Can You show us some code?

Comment: Found the anwser. thank you

Comment: Oh that's cool. You can post Your answer here for other people :)